# How to explicitly specify MachineKey with FormsAuthentication.Decrypt()

Tags: cookies, encryption, formsauthentication

I would like to decrypt a FormsAuthentication cookie but it might have been encrypted using different machine keys.  I would like to be able to try decrypting successively with let's say 3 machine keys and check if one of them is working. It would be easy if FormsAuthentication.Decrypt() would accept not only the encrypted cookie but also the machine key to use but there is no way to do this (the machine key is always retrieved from the config file). Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to specify multiple keys in the <machineKey> element.  However, if you have a crypto background, you can implement your own DataProtector which allows for key rotation.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/10/23/cryptographic-improvements-in-asp-net-4-5-pt-2.aspx (section *Introducing DataProtector*) for more information.

Warning: writing your own DataProtector is an extremely advanced scenario and should only be attempted if you have a security background and are comfortable working with cryptographic primitives.  It's very easy to introduce subtle bugs which could undermine your site security.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I understand that this functionality is only available in .NET 4.5 and I'm stuck currently with .NET 4. To limit the risks, I was investigating some tricks that would allow me to implement key rotation but still calling the framework behind for cryptography operations. For instance I could call different web services with their own web.config (and own machine key) and implementing this "decrypt" function by calling the usual FormsAuthentications.Decrypt but this looks a little bit overkilling and quite hard to maintain and extend...